# Reading subject in Python and counting upper and lower case letters

Tags: python

Subject: SAVE YOUR MUSIC AND REDEEM A SPOTIFY GIFT CARD

My assignment question asks to show the subject line from the above email and then to count the number of upper and lower case letters. I wrote the below code but nothing comes up. How do I fix the code?

```
efile = open('email.txt', 'r')
eMail = efile.readlines()
eSubject = 'Subject :'
for i in eMail:
    if eSubject in i:
        i = i[len(eSubject):]
            
        upperCase = 0
        lowerCase = 0
           
        for word in i:
            if word.isupper():
                upperCase += 1
            elif word.islower():
                lowerCase += 1
            else:
                pass 
               
        print('Subject is:', i)
        print('Upper case letters in subject:', upperCase)
        print('Lower case letters in subject:', lowerCase)
```

Comment: Did you try to check whether `if eSubject in i:` is ever the case? Did you try to do any debugging at all? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and ask a more specific question.

Comment: (Hint: does the email have a space between `Subject` and `:`? Now, look more closely at the value you used for `eSubject`.)

Answer (score 0):

`Subject: SAVE YOUR MUSIC AND REDEEM A SPOTIFY GIFT CARD` is the line you are checking, but in the code the line is `Subject :`. Notice the space after `Subject` and before `:`. Try changing `eSubject='Subject :'` to `eSubject='Subject:'`

Also, the `str` class has a function called `startswith` that checks only the beginning of the string. So you can also do `if i.startswith(eSubject):` instead.